# How to prove Conway's magic theorem for planes

Tags: proof-explanation, symmetry

I'm trying to prove Conway's magic theorem for planes for some time, but with no success, and google doesn't help much.
If someone can prove it or even share a helpful link it will help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Could you please state, or at least give a reference (link), to "Conway's Magic Theorem for planes".

Comment: https://mei.org.uk/files/conference16/PHILC-K8-PDF.pdf   or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold_notation